# Wrong Date of Birth on Indian Passport and need to travel urgently

Tags: visas

I have a question on behalf of one of my friends, his son's passport has wrong date of birth printed on it, his passport was issued 6 months ago but they just realized it now, when they were applying for Malaysian visa, they need to travel urgently in 3 days. Is there any way by which this can be resolved?

Comment: It is not possible to get the date of birth corrected in 3 days.

Comment: @AnishSheela I am not sure about it, my friend is working on it by talking with some travel agents. In the mean time, I am trying from my side to help him out.

Comment: https://www.bankbazaar.com/passport/how-to-change-date-of-birth-in-passport.html

Comment: Your best bet is a tatkal renewal application. But its unlikely to be get corrected in time. Contact the passport office.

Also, malaysian visa would be tied to a particular passport number and may not be valid for the amended passport (please confirm, mine was not).